# Joomla Plugin Back-end Options

Tags: html, css, joomla

I'm new to Joomla programming. I have built a plugin, and it works well. I have just one little annoyance that has been driving me crazy all day. When you go into the back-end to configure the plugin the options are offset by a 180px left margin. I found it was because the options are  wrapped in a div with a style="control-group" that has this margin applied.

To better understand the problem the following is condensed version of the output:

```
<div class="control-group">

<div class="control-label">
    <label id="jform_params_group_template_mapping-lbl" for="jform_params_group_template_mapping" class="hasTooltip" title="" data-original-title=""></label>
</div>

<div class="controls">
    //This is where my generated code is
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="control-label">
            <label>Uncategorised</label>
        </div>
        <div class="controls" style="float:right;margin-right:20%;">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="control-label">
            <label>Blog</label>
        </div>
        <div class="controls" style="float:right;margin-right:20%;">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="control-label">
            <label>TestingTemplate</label>
        </div>
        <div class="controls" style="float:right;margin-right:20%;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

As you can see, my controls are all inside a control. I Can't seem to find where the parent Div with the class control-group is coming from. I would prefer my generated content to be there own controls and and not sub div's.

Please let me know what part of the code you will need to look at to help me determine this issue. I feel its a part of the manifest XML, but am to new to Joomla to know.

the config portion of the manifest file is:

```
<config>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="basic">
            <field type="fta.mapping" name="group_template_mapping" addfieldpath="/plugins/system/assigntemplatebycategory/fields" description="PLG_SYSTEM_TEMPLATE_ASSIGNER_GROUP_TEMPLATE_MAPPING_DESC" label="PLG_SYSTEM_TEMPLATE_ASSIGNER_GROUP_TEMPLATE_MAPPING_LABEL" default=""/>
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</config>
```

Comment: It appears looking at http://www.ostraining.com/blog/how-tos/development/getting-started-with-jform/ that I have somehow created a field group that has a field that contains another field group with all my fields in it. Not sure if that explains it better or worse.

Comment: Can you please post the xml manifest? Field groups within fields are not a good idea

Comment: I started this based on another developers work. It appears that after a lot more reading, that there are two methods, getInput and getLabel that are used when extending jformfields. The previous developer only extended getInput and put the HTML for the sub fields and sub labels as the return for getInput. Based on what I read, I should probably re-code this as two functions, One for the Labels under the GetLabels, and one for the options under getInput. Please let me know if I'm understanding this correctly.

Comment: Joomla basically working like : you do not have to design interface of back-end, you just have give an xml file to Joomla and Joomla will displays it according to the standards they are following for all back-end parts.

This is only for convenience of the developer to reduce over-burden.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the configuration file is correct. But quite unusual since the addfieldpath is usually defined in the fields level, not the individual field i.e.

```
<config>
    <fields addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_littlehelper/elements/" name="params">
```

I'm not sure if this can be an issue.

Most likely the problem lies with the custom field. To test, simply change the field type to `text` and see if the non-required indent appears.  If so, the custom field output as defined in `/plugins/system/assigntemplatebycategory/fields/fta.mapping.php` should contain an extra wrapper.

Also try to move the `addfieldpath` attribute to the `fields` (and remove it from the `field`).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the fields was in the wrong place. I moved that and it didn't help. I figured out that the way the previous developer had it setup was the fta.mapping was a custom field type that loops through a bunch of information and builds the sub controls. the goal was to get an option for each category. I think it will be good enough for the little plugin I have.